# Disable blinking cursor from UITextField in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift3

How to disable cursor in Swift from `UITextField`? Condition - When the user logs in, then enter into application. If user can may me logout from application then not show cursor into UITextField.

Comment: simple change the tint color of your current textfield as `tintColor = [UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Did you confirm UITextFieldDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to confirm to UITextFieldDelegate and then set you textField like `yourTextField.delegate =self`
add
 `yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()`

to your code. Call resignFirstResponder to yourTextField.
and you can also use below code (According to your need).

In delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)` with checking (if) whether it has some value/text of not.

`yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "User Name", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]) textUserName.resignFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 55):

if you just don't want `cursor` then you can set it's `tintColor` to `clearColor`. In this case your textField will be active. If you want to make it inactive field then you should call `resignFirstresponder` method of `textfield`!

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 45):

For Swift 4 that works for me:

```
textField.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 7):

initially set the some bool value in `user default`, when user press the logout button set the value as `NO`

for e.g

```
UserDefaults.standard().set(true, forKey: "disalert")
```

when ever you comes to this page check the condition like as

```
let disalert: Bool = UserDefaults.standard().bool(forKey: "disalert")

      self.youtextField().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    if disalert {
        self.youtextField().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.youtextField().resignFirstresponder()
     }
```

when ever user press the login button set the user default value as

```
UserDefaults.standard().set(false, forKey: "disalert")
```

use like

```
(self.youtextField.valueForKey("textInputTraits") as! String)["insertionPointColor"] = UIColor.clearColor()
```

or set like

```
 self.youtextField().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: self.youtextField().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor() worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for SwiftUI**

```
@State var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    TextField("Placeholder Text", text: $text)
        .accentColor(.clear)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change tintcolor

self.youtextField().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

or

you make a class for text field