# Disabling keyboard input when using a UITextField + UIPickerview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

This project also click on the textfield pickerview opens, but the data shown above can be entered in the section. How can I turn it off? So just come to my choices below.

[image: view image]

If the textfield is clicked, I open the pickerview:

```
import UIKit
import NVActivityIndicatorView

struct kategoriData {
    var text : String?
    var id : String?
}

class KonuEkleViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate , NVActivityIndicatorViewable , UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var txtBaslik: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtYazi: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtLink: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnKonuAc: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtKategoriSecimi: UITextField!

    let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal
    let ConnectString = Connect.ConnectInfo
    var kategoriList = [kategoriData]()
    let GirisView = GirisViewController()
    var secilenKategori : String?

    var dbKategoriIsim : String?
    var dbKategoriId:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtKategoriSecimi.text = "Kategoriyi Seçiniz"
        KategoriGetir()
        pickerGrafik()
        txtYazi.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btnKonuAc.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GirisViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    @IBAction func btnKonuEkle(_ sender: Any) {
       GirisView.LoadingIcon(tur: 0)
        if txtBaslik.text != "" && txtYazi.text != "" && secilenKategori != nil && txtKategoriSecimi.text != "Kategoriyi Seçiniz"
        {
            KonuEkle(uye: singleton.username, baslik: txtBaslik.text!, mesaj: txtYazi.text, kategori: secilenKategori!, link: txtLink.text!)
        }
        else
        {
            GirisView.Bildiri(baslik: "UYARI", mesaj: "Boş Alanları Doldurunuz", tur: 1)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.0) {
            self.GirisView.LoadingIcon(tur: 1)
        }

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    func KonuEkle(uye:String , baslik:String ,mesaj:String , kategori:String , link:String)
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:ConnectString.conString + "/KonuEkle")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        var postString = "uye="+uye+"&&baslik="+baslik+"&&mesaj="+mesaj+"&&kategori="+kategori+"&&link="+link
        postString = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error")
            }

            if let urlContent = data
            {

                do
                {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(jsonResult)
                    if let gelenDizi = jsonResult as? NSArray
                    {
                        for i in 0..<gelenDizi.count
                        {
                            if let gelenMesaj = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["mesaj"] as? String
                            {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.Sonuc(mesaj:gelenMesaj)
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }


                }
                catch
                {
                    print("server hatası")
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.0) {
                self.GirisView.LoadingIcon(tur: 1)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }


    func Sonuc(mesaj:String)
    {
        var mesajSonuc = ""
        var mesajBaslik = ""

        if mesaj == "basarili"
        {
            mesajSonuc = "Konu Açıldı"
            mesajBaslik = "Bilgi"
        }
        else
        {
            mesajSonuc = "Bir Hata Oluştu Lütfen Destek Bölümünden Bize Ulaşın"
            mesajBaslik = "Uyarı"
        }

        let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(showCloseButton: false)
        let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
        _ = alert.addButton("Tamam") {

            self.txtLink.text = ""
            self.txtYazi.text = ""
            self.txtBaslik.text = ""
            self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        if mesajBaslik == "Bilgi"
        {
        _ = alert.showSuccess(mesajBaslik, subTitle:mesajSonuc)
        }
        else
        {
        _ = alert.showNotice(mesajBaslik, subTitle:mesajSonuc)
        }

    }
        func pickerGrafik()
    {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()

        pickerView.delegate = self

        txtKategoriSecimi.inputView = pickerView

        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height/6, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40.0))

        toolBar.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height-20.0)

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent

        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

        toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


        let defaultButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "İptal", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(KonuEkleViewController.tappedToolBarBtn))

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tamam", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(KonuEkleViewController.donePressed))

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height))

        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        label.textColor = UIColor.white

        label.text = "Kategoriyi Seçiniz"

        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        let textBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)

        toolBar.setItems([defaultButton,flexSpace,textBtn,flexSpace,doneButton], animated: true)

        txtKategoriSecimi.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    func donePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        txtKategoriSecimi.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func tappedToolBarBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        txtKategoriSecimi.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return kategoriList.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return kategoriList[row].text
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        txtKategoriSecimi.text = kategoriList[row].text
        secilenKategori = kategoriList[row].id
    }

    func KategoriGetir()
    {
        kategoriList.removeAll()
        //SADECE 1 DEFA EKLENIYOR
        self.kategoriList.append(kategoriData.init(text: "Kategoriyi Seçiniz", id: "1"))
        GirisView.LoadingIcon(tur: 0)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:ConnectString.conString + "/KategoriGetir")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        var postString = "tur=1&&kategori="
        postString = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error")
            }

            if let urlContent = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(jsonResult)
                    if let gelenDizi = jsonResult as? NSArray
                    {
                        for i in 0..<gelenDizi.count
                        {

                            if let gelenKategori = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["kategoriisim"] as? String
                            {
                                self.dbKategoriIsim = gelenKategori
                            }
                            if let gelenId = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["id"] as? String
                            {
                                self.dbKategoriId = gelenId
                            }
                            self.kategoriList.append(kategoriData.init(text: self.dbKategoriIsim, id: self.dbKategoriId))

                        }

                    }



                }
                catch
                {
                    print("error")
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
                self.GirisView.LoadingIcon(tur: 1)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

To return `false` so that entering any character by hand would be prevented.

Comment: Good answer, should do the trick! Please see my answer below for further considerations. Happy hacking!

Comment: If you're also looking for a way to fix that blanking caret, here is another SO for fixing that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503873/disable-blinking-cursor-from-uitextfield-in-swift

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an actual problem *when* running on a real iPhone device, since no keyboard will be available to do the typing :)

This is only seems like an issue when running on the iOS simulator, since you can then use your Mac keyboard as well.

---

Having said, you definitely should go with [**Mr. Hedgehog** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43688697/819340) if you still want to block text input to your field.

If, besides blocking input, you may also want to *hide the caret* on the text field, also try this:

```
class PickerBasedTextField: UITextField {
    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect { .zero }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent user from using `paste` action, you can make a subclass of `UITextField` to override `canPerformAction`.

```
public class PickerUITextField: UITextField {
    override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender 
                                            sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Here is a [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions) for list of actions.