# UITextField: Can the selection indicators be removed? not just the menu

Tags: ios, swift

When selecting characters from a UITextField, there are two (2) bars that serves as the **selection indicators**

I know that you can hide it if you set the color to clear, but if i want the tint to stay blue and remove the 2 selection indicator bars, is it possible?

EDIT:

not just the menu guys, I also need to remove the indicators (the blue pin with a circle head) while letting it stay blue.

Is there any way to remove them?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503873/disable-blinking-cursor-from-uitextfield-in-swift 
Try this

Comment: hmm. i don't think it is the same CURSOR as the one mentioned in that post. Moreover, I also want the menu to not popup (the one containing select all, copy, paste, etc)

Comment: https://blog.apoorvmote.com/remove-cursor-and-disable-copypaste-for-uitextfield/

Try this

Comment: I think you have probably found the solution already. But if you want to remove the indicators, I think `yourTextField.tintColor = .clear` should work.

Comment: People flagging questions as duplicate when they have no clue omg...